# Android - NullPointerException in android.security.IKeystoreService.del for Huawei devices

Tags: android, kotlin, android-keystore, huawei-mobile-services, tink

When uploading our app to the Google Play store, google's pre-launch report indicates that the app is crashing with a null pointer exception. The issue is regarding KeyStore implementation in Huawei devices only.

Stacktrace:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int android.security.IKeystoreService.del(java.lang.String, int)' on a null object reference
       at android.security.KeyStore.delete(KeyStore.java:186)
       at android.security.Credentials.deletePrivateKeyTypeForAlias(Credentials.java:292)
       at android.security.Credentials.deleteAllTypesForAlias(Credentials.java:251)
       at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreKeyPairGeneratorSpi.generateKeyPair(AndroidKeyStoreKeyPairGeneratorSpi.java:464)
       at java.security.KeyPairGenerator$Delegate.generateKeyPair(KeyPairGenerator.java:699)
       at com.example.utility.crypto.KeyStoreHelper.createKeys(Unknown Source)
       at com.example.utility.crypto.KeyStoreHelper.createKeys(Unknown Source)
       at com.example.activities.register.SplashActivity$1.run(Unknown Source)
       at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:255)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:776)
```

I am using Google's [Tink](https://github.com/google/tink) library for Keystore implementation. Library has nothing to do with error. Error still occurs without library.

Below is code:

```
@Throws(Exception::class)
private fun getOrGenerateNewKeysetHandle(): KeysetHandle {
    return AndroidKeysetManager.Builder()
        .withSharedPref(this, "KEYSET", "PREF")
        .withKeyTemplate(AeadKeyTemplates.AES256_GCM)
        .withMasterKeyUri(REIWA_MASTER_KEY_URI)
        .build()
        .keysetHandle
}
```

I think it has to do something with the device's keystore implementation.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: looks library problem or something I don't know :-) | Looks like `IKeystoreService` is null

Comment: @Toaster No, it has nothing to do with library. Error still occurs without library.

Comment: Some piece of code where you call : `IKeystoreService.del` or do similar lib calls also needs to be added to help the answerer

Comment: We can't know what's the issue is.Put the code where you are using utility.crypto.KeyStoreHelper.createKeys calls.

Comment: did you find an answer @Rajesh?

Comment: No @rustyMagnet, I haven't found any solution.

Answer (score 0):

Disable Keystore integration with `AndroidKeysetManager.doNotUseKeystore()`.